# Efficient zooming in D3 Scatterplot (React + D3 Implementation)

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I am creating an interactive scatterplot of *n* points using D3 and React, and I want to enable zooming/panning.

I am following [this tutorial](https://swizec.com/blog/the-two-ways-to-build-a-zoomable-dataviz-component-with-d3zoom-and-react/) (and its codepan implementation). My main problem is that this approach *re-renders* the plot every time a zoom event occurs, causing a lag as *n* increases.

The value of *n* for my current dataset is about 3,000 points (and it lags), however, I am looking for an approach that scales for up to ~1 million points.

What is typically the largest number of data points one can visualize using D3 without causing the page to lag? Is there an efficient way of accomplishing this?

Comment: A million data points on a scatter plot is too many in my opinion. Have a look at converting it to a density plot or heatmap like this one https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/density2d.html

Comment: @SimonD One missing piece in my question is that it'll be an interactive visualization, not just a view (in which case your idea would be great). I found a wrapper over D3 that uses WebGL for faster processing ([D3FC](https://d3fc.io/)). I'm trying to understand and recreate [this example](https://colineberhardt.github.io/d3fc-webgl-hathi-explorer/#) right now.